# Unable to get image src url with Cheerio

Tags: javascript, cheerio

At the moment I am trying to get value in `src=` of

```
<div class="page-break no-gaps">
  <img id="image-0" src="https://foo.bar/image.jpg" class="wp-image" alt="Title">
</div>
```

with the following code:

```
getImageSrc(imageObj: Cheerio | undefined): string {
    let image
    image = imageObj?.attr('src')
    console.log(image)
}
```

selector code:
`chapterDetailsSelector = 'div.page-break > img'`

However all I am getting is undefined

EDITED - add more context

Comment: The code looks fine, but what is the value of the imageObj variable?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I tried console.log(imageObj) as a test awhile back but I didn't see it in logs for some reason. There's another portion of my code that is quite similar but uses the attribute 'data-src' and that works

Answer (score 0):

View source HTML is not the same as what is fetched by cheerio.

Seems like the image URL is in `attr('data-cfsrc')` rather than `attr('data')` when fetched with cheerio.

Comment: Correct, although note that Cheerio doesn't do fetching, axios or fetch or some other HTTP library does.